# change the column in csv using php

Tags: javascript, php, csv

in the code i used csv file in which i want to edit the rows of 3rd coulmn as want to make them a http link by using  tag but i cant do that. right now the code chowing only the link but i want to make them hyperlink

```html
<html>
<head>
</head><body>
<table width="10%" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0" border="1" ;">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>A</th>
                <th>B</th>
                <th>C</th>
                
         <?php

$f = fopen("http://localhost/csv/cr.csv", "r");
while (($line = fgetcsv($f)) !== false) {
        echo "<tr>";
  $data = count($line); 
        foreach ($line as $cell) {
                echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($cell) . "</td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>\n";
}
fclose($f);
?>
</tr>
</thead>
</table>
</body>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
<?php
$f = fopen("http://localhost/csv/cr.csv", "r");
while (($line = fgetcsv($f)) !== false) {
    if (!isset($line[2]))  {
        continue;
    }
    echo "<tr><td><a href='url'>" . htmlspecialchars($line[2]) . "</a></td></tr>";
}
fclose($f);
?>
```

Comment: no its not opening the url and i want 3rd column as url not all of them @daniel

Comment: i have edited, this will check if 3rd column is not empty, and will echo it as a url,
if you want empty cells to be printed add tr tags before the if statement

Comment: its still wrong but thanks i got the hint from this @daniel